# Username & password authentication with passing other parameters in Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, authentication, parameters

I am trying to send SMS from an SMS provider API with username and password authentication including other parameters using Javascript. More elaborately, I have to send SMS using the following link :

http://sms-pp.sapmobileservices.com/cmn/account_name/account_name.sms

I have to pass other parameters including message text. I have tried creating form and passed other parameters as value of hidden input fields. But it doesn't work. finally, I have used ajax as following :

```
     $.ajax({
url: 'http://sms-pp.sapmobileservices.com/cmn/account_name/account_name.sms',

method: 'get',

dataType: 'json',

async: false,

data: '{Text:A sample message}',

beforeSend: function(req) {
        req.setRequestHeader('Authorization', make_base_auth('username',               'password')); 
    },

success: function (){
        alert('Thanks for your comment!'); 
    }

});
```

It outputs '401 Unauthorized'. can anyone help me with the this.

Comment: Why don’t you use the `username` and `password` options of jQuery.ajax?

Comment: i have given my username and password with username and password property of jQuery.ajax. But it's not working.

Comment: And you are sure that the service is actually using HTTP Auth, and not something lese?

Comment: yes, i have to do a http post to that url.

Comment: Why are you setting the method to `get` then …?

Comment: i just wanted to authenticate usename and password somehow, that's why i have tried both 'post' and 'get' method. But unfortunately, it's not working whatever i do in my code.

Comment: Any kind of documentation available for that service you are trying to use here?

Comment: it's a documentation link 

http://www.textmarketer.co.uk/pdfebooks/Simple_Bulk_Sending_API.pdf

Comment: Are you sure that’s the same service? Because then you would just simple have to make a request as described here: http://www.textmarketer.co.uk/basic-connectivity

Comment: no, it's not the same service , i have found this documentation similar to the service (as i am told about the service) i'm using ...

Comment: Yeah, using a documentation for a another service which might do things _completely_ different is totally helpful … sorry, I’m out.

Comment: it's okay.. but i am just given only this documentation link... not anything else... and thank you for enthusiasm...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the HTTP request type is POST. 
Second, the data you are trying to send is not in good format.
Third, the data type should be text.

Having that in mind, you need to send the data in the following structure:

[MSISDN]
List=
[MESSAGE]
Text=
Binary=
Length=
[SETUP]
Class=
DCS=
PID=
MobileNotification=
MailAckType=
ValidityPeriod=
DestinationPort=
OriginatorPort=
[END]

Check this documentation for more info : https://community.sapmobileservices.com/sybase/attachments/sybase/EnterpriseTKB/84/3/SAP_SMS_365-enterprise_service-SMTP_Interface_Specification%20-%20v2.pdf